# Div expanding horizontally with text

Tags: javascript, css, html, expand

I wonder, if its possible to create a div that is horizontally expanding with the containing text. (Pure CSS would be good, but I suppose thats not possible)

Lets say it has a fixed height, a min-width and no max-width. If the text is short enough to fit in there, the box won't change. If the Box is full, it starts expanding to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this posible to do with just HTML and CSS by doing something like this? :

---

```
html:
<div class="text_box">...Content goes here...</div>

css:
.text_box {
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width: 1000px; /* if you want a max size. can also be 100% or something else */
}
```

Comment: No. If theres a lot of text, the box will expand to the right until it reaches 1000px. Than it will jump to the next line. What I want to do is letting the text fill the box and expanding it, when its full.

Comment: Nope doesnt work, check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hRDqs/). Box 1 looks fine, box 2 should wrap and stay at 200px width but doesnt. Box 3 looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `<input type='text' id='textboxsizedemo' onChange='changeSize(this);' name='text' />`. If onChange doesn't work use onKeyDown and then use this javascript:

```
function changeSize(elem)
{
  var widthperchar = 5; //The width per character
  var textlength = elem.value.length;
  var newwidth = textlength * widthperchar;
  if(newwidth < 200)
  {
    newwidth = 200;
  }
  elem.style.width = newwidth;
}
```

Comment: you can enhance this by passing `this` to the function - saves the 2 calls to `getElementById`

Comment: No, you didn't - you need to pass in a reference and use that. *I've* updated your code :)

Comment: Yeah, Sorry :P
@Lord_Mord Yes, you can just change elem to document.getElementById('DIV_ID_HERE') or use a similar getElement function.